# The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type. OData Service

Tags: c#, odata

**The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.**
I'm Using OData Service , If i use ApiControler then its working.

And Sometime also throw **The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable.**

```
public string SaveData(string ApiName, string JsonParam)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:9093/api/" + ApiName + "/");
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                sw.Write(JsonParam);
                sw.Flush();
            }
            HttpWebResponse rep = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            var outputData = new StreamReader(rep.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            return outputData;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "ERROR";
        }

    }    


public class EmployeesController : ODataController
{   
    [HttpPost]
    public HR_EmployeeMaster Post([FromBody]HR_EmployeeMaster value)
    {
        HrEmployeeServiceFacadeClient employeeObj = new HrEmployeeServiceFacadeClient();
        string employeeJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(value.EmployeeId)) || Convert.ToString(value.EmployeeId) == "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
        {
            value.EmployeeId = Guid.NewGuid();
            var employeeResponse = employeeObj.Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            var employeeResponse = employeeObj.Update(value);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you set the ContentType in the request to just "application/json"?

Comment: log the json payload when you have that error